# Bar chart with different 1 and 2 bars per group

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar chart that has both groups of 2 bars and a single bar. When I run my code below, the x-axis ticker for the the single bars does not show. Is `bar group size={0}{1}` not allowed or is there something else I am doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{
    % #1: index in the group(0,1,2,...)
    % #2: number of plots of that group
    bar group size/.style 2 args={
        /pgf/bar shift={%
                % total width = n*w + (n-1)*skip
                % -> subtract half for centering
                -0.5*(#2*\pgfplotbarwidth + (#2-1)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/bar group skip})  + 
                % the '0.5*w' is for centering
                (.5+#1)*\pgfplotbarwidth + #1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/bar group skip}},%
    },
    bar group skip/.initial=2pt,
    plot 0/.style={blue,fill=blue!30!white,mark=none},%
    plot 1/.style={red,fill=red!30!white,mark=none},%
}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=\textwidth,
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
        x axis line style={opacity=0},
        enlargelimits=0.05,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=0},
        ybar,
        bar width=15pt,
        nodes near coords,
        symbolic x coords={20 Q2,20 Q3,20 Q4,21 Q1,21 Q2,21 Q3,21 Q4,22 Q1},
        xtick=data ]
        \addplot[plot 0,bar group size={0}{2}]
        coordinates { (20 Q2,0.5) (20 Q3,1.2) (20 Q4, 2.4) (21 Q1,4.8) (21 Q2,9) (21 Q3,12) (21 Q4,30) (22 Q1,60)};

        \addplot[plot 0,bar group size={0}{1}] 
        coordinates { (21 Q1,6.2) (21 Q2,11.6) (21 Q3,22) (21 Q4,41.5) (22 Q1,78.3)};    

        \legend{First,Second}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Tex. Can you concretize what you want to achieve? I don´t know what the graph should look like i the end.

Comment: It also seems that you have "borrowed" the code somewhere. If that is true, could you indicate the source as well?